# Java: Generic List to Set conversion and vice versa

Tags: java, collections

I Need a java function which converts from `java.util.List` to `java.util.Set` and vice versa, independent of type of objects in the `List/Set`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like `List.addAll` and `Set.addAll`?

Answer (score 8):

Most of the class of the [java collection framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) have a constructor that take a collection of element as a parameter. You should use your prefered implementation ton do the conversion for exameple (with `HashSet` and `ArrayList`):

```
public class MyCollecUtils {

    public static <E> Set<E> toSet(List<E> l) {
        return new HashSet<E>(l);
    }

    public static <E> List<E> toSet(Set<E> s) {
        return new ArrayList<E>(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you already mentioned: most take a collection as a parameter to their c-tor. So why not use that too: `toSet(Collection<E> c)` and `toSet(Collection<E> c)`?

Comment: In a general case, actually, you won't even build function for it, just use the constructors. As we are in a specific case, where the question is conversion from List to Set and vice-versa, I prefer to specify the kind of collection attended.

Comment: This code is so simple and basic that maybe it doesn't deserve a function at all. Util.toSet(col) is not really better than new HashSet<E>(col). You can then choose the actual implementation of your class, and can convert from any collection type to any other type.

Comment: Nicolas: it is exactly what i've written.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static <E> Set<E> getSetForList(List<E> lst){
  return new HashSet<E>(lst);//assuming you don't care for duplicate entry scenario :)
}

public static <E> List<E> getListForSet(Set<E> set){
  return new ArrayList<E>(set);// You can select any implementation of List depending on your scenario
}
```

Comment: Can we convert a list of a custom model to HashSet?

Comment: As long as your custom model implements hashCode and equals method properly yes, you can use the first method from answer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of one function you can have two function to implement this functionality:

```
// Set to List
public List setToList(Set set) {
    return new ArrayList(set);
}

// List to Set
public Set listToSet(List list) {
    return new HashSet(list);
}
```

In a single function:

```
public Collection convertSetList(Collection obj) {
    if (obj instanceof java.util.List) {
         return new HashSet((List)obj);
    } else if(obj instanceof java.util.Set) {
         return new ArrayList((Set)obj);
    }    
    return null;
}
```

**Example:** (updated)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set s = new HashSet();
        List l = new ArrayList();

        s.add("1");s.add("2");s.add("3");
        l.add("a");l.add("b");l.add("c");

        Collection c1 = convertSetList(s);
        Collection c2 = convertSetList(l);

        System.out.println("c1 type is : "+ c1.getClass());
        System.out.println("c2 type is : "+ c2.getClass());        
    }

    public static Collection convertSetList(Collection obj) {
        if (obj instanceof java.util.List) {
            System.out.println("List!");
            return (Set)new HashSet((List) obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof java.util.Set) {
            System.out.println("Set!");
            return (List)new ArrayList((Set) obj);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknow type!");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed my -1, but I still don't think it's wise to do it like you suggest in `convertSetList`: since neither a `List` or `Set` is returned (but a `Collection`), there will need to be some casting if the reference  to either the `List` or `Set` is needed. Also, when something other than a `List` or `Set` is passed, `null` is returned (not good, IMO). Lastly there still is no use of generics in your code, making it Java 1.4.2 code (from ages ago!) :)

Comment: the above piece of code working for me. as per the user's requirement he wants to a function. Obviously he needs to cast or do some validation. thats why written like that. correct me if am wrong. thanks.